# Wildcards don't match pattern containing functions from Mathematica Quantum Computing library

Tags: pattern-matching, packages

Here's a cut-down example using the [Mathematica Quantum Computing library](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/quantum/). Why is the second wildcard-based expression not matching?

```
Needs["Quantum`Computing`"];
state = zz075NonCommutativeTimes[xrot[zz080Operator[1]][10], xrot[zz080Operator[1]][9]];

(*This matches*)
matchSpecific[zz075NonCommutativeTimes[xrot[zz080Operator[a_]][b_], xrot[zz080Operator[c_]][d_]]] := "Great Matching";
matchSpecific[state]

(*This doesn't match even though it has unqualified wildcards*)
matchWildcards[zz075NonCommutativeTimes[_, _]] := "Great Wildcards"
matchWildcards[state]
```

Additionally, in this example is there a way of flagging the `before___` pattern so that the `zz075NonCommutativeTimes` evaluation does not extract it out as part of a `Times`?

```
Needs["Quantum`Computing`"];
SetQuantumObject[mygate1];
SetQuantumObject[mygate2];
SetQuantumObject[mygate3];

(*Keeps its form when it's evaluated*)
zz075NonCommutativeTimes[mygate1, mygate2, mygate3] // FullForm

(*
When evaluated, the before___ pattern is extracted out as part of a Times
head because the evaluation assumes it's a scalar.
*) 
zz075NonCommutativeTimes[before___, mygate2, mygate3] // FullForm
```

This is the corresponding output:

```
zz075NonCommutativeTimes[mygate1,mygate2,mygate3]
Times[Pattern[before,BlankNullSequence[]],zz075NonCommutativeTimes[mygate2,mygate3]]
```

The desired / expected output of the pattern once `before___` has been tagged is:

```
zz075NonCommutativeTimes[Pattern[before,BlankNullSequence[]],mygate2,mygate3]
```

Comment: It would really depend on the definition of `matchWildcards`.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. The definition of matchWildcards is there in the code I posted, if I haven't misunderstood?

Comment: I must be blind...

Comment: Okay, it matched for me. I did not install or load that package though.

Comment: That's right; same for me. However, if you install and load the package it won't match. I don't know, in principle, what within the package could interfere with this sort of matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression `state` has evaluated, and no longer matches the pattern.

```
state = 
 zz075NonCommutativeTimes[xrot[zz080Operator[1]][10], 
  xrot[zz080Operator[1]][9]];
FullForm @ state

(* Times[xrot[zz080Operator[1]][9],xrot[zz080Operator[1]][10]] *)
```

which won't match any pattern with `Head` `zz075NonCommutativeTimes`, unless that pattern also evaluates.

A more accessible example might be `Plot`, which evaluates to a `Graphics` when given the right arguments

```
MatchQ[
 Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}],
 _Plot
 ]
(* False *)

MatchQ[
 Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}],
 _Graphics
 ]
(* True *)
```

Comment: It's documented here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationInPatternsRulesAndDefinitions.html . As always, easy to find the documentation once you know the answer ;)

Comment: I can now use `HoldPattern` to get the rule to do what I want, but it's a bit of an ugly solution. What would be better is to stop the evaluation of `zz075NonCommutativeTimes` from assuming that `before___` is a scalar that can be extracted into a `Times`. I've added text to my original question starting with "Additionally". I've read through the Notation.m code and can't work out how to communicate to Mathematica that the *pattern* is to be considered a QuantumObject. I appreciate that this is probably specific to the library that I'm using.

Comment: This has worked for me: `Unprotect[QuantumScalarQ]`  `QuantumScalarQ[p_Pattern] := False`  `Protect[QuantumScalarQ]`